# Possible to create newsfeed ad hidden from my page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads

We are a ads company, and we have a page on FB. We are trying to use ads API to create tons of newsfeed ads. In my experiment a newsfeed ad is created successfully, but it's displayed on our page as well. When there're tons of ads, our page will be flooded. I know I can change the post to be hidden, or use unpublished post, but will FB users be able to view such ads?
 I mean, I want these ads to be advertised by FB on user's wall but not on our company's wall.

Comment: Ever thought that's purposeful on facebook side?

Comment: Of course not. That's why I'm asking. So, are you saying that's mission impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`I know I can change the post to be hidden, or use unpublished post,`

That is how you create news feed ad for a post from your page which is not not on the Page's timeline. It's documented here and the feature exists for the exact use-case you've outlined in your question : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#unpub_scheduled_posts

Comment: simply set published attribute to false when creating post.